# Inserting ground control points in ASP NASA?

Tags: dem

I am using PLEIADES stereo images and  the Nasa software : Ames Stereo Pipeline (ASP) in order to generate a Data Elevation Model (DEM).

In addition to that, I have some ground control points and I would like to use them to improve DEM quality. How do I do it ?